# Porting a .exe setup and mono framework on mac

Tags: macos, mono, installation, nsis

I have a requirement to deploy a windows .net application on a Mac OS. As i am a novice to mac, i need a step by step procedure to bundle the Mono Framework and my application setup(built in NSIS). Uses should be be able to directly click and install the application on a Mac. If possible please provide a simple step by step procedure how to go about with the process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure whether i understood what you want to accomplish, so the following is based on some wild guesses

- to build an installer for os x, have a look at [packagemaker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/packagemaker.1.html) (here's a [guide](http://www.osxgnu.org/info/osxpackages.html)).
- to run a nsis installer on os x, you will need [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) or [winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/)
- to get the contents of nsis installers, try extracting them with [keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/) or [theunarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)

maybe you could be more specific or rephrase what you're up to!