# How to make a .pkg out of a .exe

Tags: macos, mono, installation, nsis

There is a windows Forms application of which i have made a setup in NSIS. Can i convert this setup built in NSIS into a .pkg for users to install the same on a Mac?.  IF NOT, then....
Alternately, is there a way to bundle my application files(comprising of 1 exe, few dll's and some other resource files) and make a .pkg so that i can let users install it on a Mac.
  I have read "http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager#Creating_an_Installer_package" but as i a novice, i need to know whether the above(queries 1 or 2) are possible and if so, please give me a step by step procedure to go about creating a package.
 I as a novice, am in Dire need of help on this.

Thanks,
Bomzinho

Answer (score 0):

as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359590/porting-a-exe-setup-and-mono-framework-on-mac/17375410#17375410) before, you can create an installer for os x with [packagebuild](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html). There is no automatic way, developed by anyone and known to be currently publicly available, to convert an nsis script (or executable). You are always welcome to contribute to community.